# Working with subdirectories with RMarkdown

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm writing a markdown document but I want to organize my folders so that it's easier to store all my things for my document.

I have some images that I want to put in the document but they are stored in a subfolder called `Images` relative to the .RMD document.

How can I set this so that I don't have this error:

```
pandoc: Could not fetch New%20file.png
New file.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 67
Execution halted
```

Here is my code:

````
---
title: "Markdown Tutorial"
author: "Me"
date: "August 18, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.path='Images/')
```

# Creating and Setting Your Document

To create your first markdown document, open up RStudio and clic on File > New File > R Markdown... 

![Creating a new Markdow](New file.png)
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the full path in your Rmarkdown:

```
# Creating and Setting Your Document

To create your first markdown document, open up RStudio and clic on File > New File > R Markdown... 

![Creating a new Markdow](Images/fig1.png)
```

Comment: OK! I tried this but it wasn't working. Just because I was adding a slash in from of the folder name. DON'T DO THIS: `![Creating a new Markdow](/Images/fig1.png)`

Comment: Right, your working directory is already set, so no leading slash is needed.