# How to render documents in sub-directories with rmarkdown::render_site()?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

For example I have a markdown file called `index.md` in the root folder and another markdown file in a subfolder called `docs/tools/git.md`. When I run `render_site()`, `index.html` is generated from `index.md`, but no document is generated from `docs/tools/git.md`.

The help page of [rmardown::render_site](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rmarkdown/versions/1.6/topics/render_site) says:

> R Markdown (.Rmd) and plain markdown (.md) files in the root directory are rendered.

I have tried to add `include: ["docs/tools/git.md"]` to the `_site.yml` but this doesn't help.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022613/working-with-subdirectories-with-rmarkdown) is related, but I already know how to work with sub directories in knitr.

What I want to know is how to render documents in sub-directories with rmarkdown::render_site()?

Comment: You cannot. That is by design. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rmd-website.html If you are serious about Rmd-based websites, it is time to consider blogdown now.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui , I thought blogdown was experimental and I wasn't sure it would be maintained over the long term. Is [blogdown](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown) going to replace [rmarkdown sites](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/rmarkdown_websites.html)?

Comment: blogdown is a totally serious project and I have spent days and nights on it for several months. It is not experimental; it is just not on CRAN yet (will be soon). RE: blogdown vs rmarkdown sites, you seems not to have read what I pointed you to carefully. These are two options, and you decide which to use.

Comment: I know it's not the best place for discussion, but I don't get it why `rmarkdown::render_site()` doesn't allow for sub-directories? It seems to be just an obstacle to make people use blogdown?

Comment: I don't use blogdown, I still use rmarkdown's flat hierarchy for my personal blog. Sticking with the simple version (rmarkdown) might have avoided me some pain with hugo updates, as explained in this [2020 December update on blogdown](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2020-12-new-year-new-blogdown/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have sub-directories with `rmardown::render_site()`  according to the author Yihui Xie who referred to the [Rmarkdown website page](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/rmd-website.html) of the bookdown documentation in a comment above:

> "Before blogdown was invented, there was actually a relatively simple way to render websites using rmarkdown. The structure of the website has to be a flat directory of Rmd files (no subdirectories for Rmd files) and a configuration file in which you can specify a navigation bar for all your pages and output format options."

It goes on to specify that these simple sites are still useful in some cases. The first two points:

> - "You are familiar with generating single-page HTML output from R Markdown, and all you want is to extend this to generating multiple pages from multiple Rmd files."
> - "It suffices to use a flat directory of Rmd files. You do not write a blog or need RSS feeds."